# OpenAPI speccy lint tool, "Specification schema is invalid."

Tags: openapi

Using OpenApi speccy V0.8.1 tool. Tool will display website but will not lint.
Following is stripped down hello world example that will not lint.

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/hello_query": {
            "get": {
                "description": "Hello query",
                "operationId": "hello_query",
                "responses": {
                    "200":  {
                        "description": "search results matching criteria",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `"swagger": "2.0"`, OpenAPI 3.0's `openapi` field requires a [3-digit version number](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#versions):

```
"openapi": "3.0.0"
```

or

```
"openapi": "3.0.1"
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks.